# Android video live streaming

Tags: android, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, http-streaming

I am in big trouble, I could not play m3u8 file in my android videoview but it is so easy in iPhone. I googled and visited several forums and all are saying that it is not possible. But I tried vitamio(http://vov.io/vitamio/) and it can stream for 5 to 6 seconds. That is there is a chance to stream, but how ?

If the m3u8 streaming in android is hard, How can stream from an IPcamera to my android device?

If any one know about this, Please give a response, I am very thankful for your response because i spend much more time for this.

Comment: HLS is supported since Android 2.3.3 (API level 10), What API level do you use to build your app? Even vitamio requires Android 2.1+ for HLS.

Comment: Hello yorkw, would you like to explain it in more details? I also used vitamioBundle too, and got the same problem. Built Device : Samsung Galaxy Tab 7", version 2.2.1. Developed tool : Target SDK : Android 4.3, Min SDK : 8. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried the devices having Android versions 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.3.6,and 4.0.
The vitamio application can stream the url for 5 to 6 seconds in all devices except the device HTC onex having android version 4.0.

My code for calling simple m3u8 url is given below..
Many thanks yorkw.

Activity:

```
       package com.livestrean;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class streamplayer extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


     private String path = "An m3u8 Url";


     private VideoView mVideoView;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.surface_view_1);
            mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

                mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));                
                mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                mVideoView.requestFocus();              
                mVideoView.postInvalidateDelayed(100);        
                mVideoView.start();



        }catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(streamplayer.this,"Error Occured:- " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/surface_view" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks